# dplyr - grouped counting and dividing

Tags: r, dataframe

I attempted a search online but couldn't find a way how to tally and divide.

What I want to accomplish is that all the values of `Geslacht` are counted per `Operatie` and is divided by the number of people (row) in that `Operatie`. So I want to have a ratio (*single value*) between 0's and 1's for each value of `Operatie`. `Operatie` goes up to a 100.

To write it algebraically `df$ratio <- sum(df$Geslacht(grouped_by = "Operatie")) / n`

Data looks like this:

```
       Operatie Geslacht jaar_ervaring
1        1        0             5     
2        1        1             5 
3        1        0             3  
4        2        0             5 
5        2        1             5 
6        2        1             3
```

```
x(operatie 1) == 0+1+0 = 1/3 == .333  
x(operatie 2) == 0+1+1 = 2/3 == .666
...
x(operatie 100)
```

My attempt or blockade;

```
new_df <- df %>%
  group_by(Operatie , Geslacht ) %>%
  count()
```

Gives:

```
Operatie Geslacht     n
     <int>    <dbl> <int>
1        1        0     2
2        1        1     1
3        2        0     1
4        2        1     2
```

Do I have to specify something in count() or do I need a different function? Something with forest and trees.

Thanks in advance

**SOLUTION:**

```
new_df <- df %>%
  drop_na() %>% # if we want "ignore" NAs when counting
  group_by(Operatie) %>%
  summarise(ratio = sum(Geslacht)/n())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
new_df <- df %>% group_by(Operatie) %>%
  summarise(ratio = sum(Geslacht)/n())
```

gives:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  Operatie ratio
     <dbl> <dbl>
1        1 0.333
2        2 0.667
```

Comment: You would have an example where `dplyr` ignores NAs but still counts the others that are not missing?

Comment: Try running your dataframe through the `drop_na` argument first and then grouping and summarizing

Comment: `new_df <- df %>% drop_na() %>% group_by(Operatie) %>%
  summarise(ratio = sum(Geslacht)/n())` Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Base R approach:

```
aggregate(df$Geslacht, list(df$Operatie), mean)

  Group.1         x
1       1 0.3333333
2       2 0.6666667
```